# How to use sed to replace a config file's variable?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, replace

I've been looking online for this answer and cannot seem to find it.

I have a config file that contains:

```
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
VAR3=VALUE3
VAR4=VALUE4
VAR5=VALUE5
VAR6=VALUE6
```

And I want to change `VAR5`'s value from `VALUE5` to `VALUE10`. Unfortunately, I do not know the value of `VALUE5` so I cannot search for it. So basically I need to use sed (or whatever) to replace the value of `VAR5` to another value.

Comment: Where is "VALUE10" coming from?  Is it coming from another line in this same file?  Or is it just some arbitrary value?

Comment: VAR5 in my config file is USER_INSTALL_DIR and VALUE10 is anything, it could be garbage. I want to make VAR5 or in my case USER_INSTALL_DIR set to a variable I pass to it via a bash script. The following worked for me thanks to anubhava's comment. I also replaced the slashes with commas since the parameter that my bash script takes will contain slashes since it's passing a user directory.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can try this sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(VAR5=\).*/\1VALUE10/' file
```

It gives:

```
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
VAR3=VALUE3
VAR4=VALUE4
VAR5=VALUE10
VAR6=VALUE6
```

Comment: +1. I just want to provide another, a tad simpler (but less potent, works only if we know exactly the beginning) : `sed -i.bak 's/^VAR5=.*/VAR5=VALUE10/' file`

Comment: The problem with both of these answers is that it requires you to know the value of VAR5. In my case, you do not know the value of VAR5 so you want to find "VAR5=" and find the string between that and the new line.

Comment: Value of `VAR5` was `VALUE5` in your example and this answer didn't need to know `VALUE5`

Comment: If you read the answer again it is actually finding `VAR5=` and value after that. This is replaced by `VAR5=` and new value.

Comment: Oh woops my mistake. I read it over too fast. Sorry about that. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: is there a way to replace the value with a variable?

Comment: i tried this sed -i.bak 's/^\(the.name.of.my.property=\).*/\""$encrypted""/' myFile.properties but it doesn't work

Comment: `sed -i.bak "s/^the\.name\.of\.my\.property=.*/$encrypted/" myFile.properties`

Answer (score 7):

Even though the answer has been added to the question. I spent some time on how it works, I would like add some facts and my version of the answer,

```
sed -i 's,^\(THISISMYVARIABLE[ ]*=\).*,\1'THISISMYVALUE',g' config.cfg
```

***Explanation:***

- As a basic of `sed 's/find_this/replace_with/'`, we are saying sed to search and replace. Also remember there are multiple other delimiters that we can use instead of `/`. Here `,` is used.
- Here we find the line that matches `^\(THISISMYVARIABLE[ ]*=\).*` . This means we are grouping the match `THISISMYVARIABLE[ ]*=` . (`[ ]*` to cover if there are any spaces after the key)
- In replace section `\1` is a back-reference. We are referencing the first group in the regular expression that we used for match.

Comment: THISISMYVALUE is without quotation marks according to the op. Why spaces before equal, seems overcorrect! The rest is valid, back reference is the right name..

Comment: @Kannan, thanks! I was such a noob when I joined SO that I thought it was a good idea to put the answer in the question and so I removed it.

Answer (score 4):

You can say:

```
sed '/^VAR5=/s/=.*/=VALUE10/' filename
```

To make in the change to the file *in-place*, use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i '/^VAR5=/s/=.*/=VALUE10/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/\(^VAR5=\).*/ s//\1VALUE10/' YourFile
```

Under AIX/KSH

```
$ cat sample.txt
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
VAR3=VALUE3
VAR4=VALUE4
VAR5=VALUE5
VAR6=VALUE6

$ sed '/\(^VAR5=\).*/ s//\1VALUE10/' sample.txt
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
VAR3=VALUE3
VAR4=VALUE4
VAR5=VALUE10
VAR6=VALUE6
```

and for replacement in file

```
cat <> YourFile | sed '/\(^VAR5=\).*/ s//\1VALUE10/'

$ cat <> sample.txt | sed '/\(^VAR5=\).*/ s//\1VALUE10/'
$ cat sample.txt
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR2=VALUE2
VAR3=VALUE3
VAR4=VALUE4
VAR5=VALUE10
VAR6=VALUE6
```

To be POSIX (on `sed` part, not `cat`) compliant (sed `--posix` on gnu sed and natively traditionnal sed on non linux system)

Comment: There's nothing POSIX about a [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). Also that diamond `<>` looks completely misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

sed -r 's/^(VAR5=).*/\1REPLACEMENT/'

The value of VAR5 will be replaced with REPLACEMENT.