# sed command with regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, sed, command

I have a config file that stores every configuration in a line which starts with a @ like:

```
.
@server_ip=192.168.0.1
@path=/home/me
```

i want to write a **sed replace in-place** command that replace the ip which is in front of **@server_ip**. The point is the **192.168.0.1** is for example and the real config can be any ip or empty. 
**EDIT** How can i write the command?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried something?

Comment: You should really specify what you want the value replaced with — but it is very elementary use of `sed`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sed to replace a config file's variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568515/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-a-config-files-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/^\(@server_ip=\).*/\1127.0.0.1/' file
```

or with variable:

```
newip="127.0.0.1"
sed 's/^\(@server_ip=\).*/\1'"$newip"'/' file
```

Output:

```
@server_ip=127.0.0.1
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.