# Modifying pi-config values using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python script that will toggle my pi3 /boot/config.txt files gpu_mem=156 parameter for desktop and game mode. I have tried looking into [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) but the config file I'm using uses a simpler format of simply:

```
var1=value0
var2=value1
```

I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: Why not read the contents of the file, split each line and then split line by `=` sign?

Comment: Please explain, I feel my great frustration has a simple solution...

Comment: I recommend that you do this with your system's file-processing command.  For instance, in UNIX/Linux, you can handle this with `sed`.  If desired, you can execute the system command from a Python script.

Comment: Yup, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568515/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-a-config-files-variable

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a text file to store your config you can parse it like

```
with open('config.txt', 'r') as config:
    for line in config.read().splitlines():
        var, val = line.split('=')
        print var, val
```

But if you are storing your config that can be parsed by `ConfigParser` in the following format

```
[global]
var1=value0
var2=value1
```

Then you can parse it with `ConfigParser` like so

```
import ConfigParser

config_parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config_parser.read('config.txt')
print config_parser.get('global', 'var1')
```