# Access and append local file from remote host in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, file, ssh, remote-server

From my bash script, doing ssh login to the remote host. Sending my config file along with a script to the remote host to access the variables. Code is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/shell/config.sh
script=$(cat <<\____HERE

   pubkeyarray=()
   privkeyarray=()
   for (( w=1; w<=3; w++))
   do
        cleos create key --file key[$w].txt
        privatekey=$(sed -ne 's/^Private key: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' ~/key[$w].txt)
        pubkey=$(sed -ne 's/^Public key: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' ~/key[$w].txt)
        pubkeyarray+=("$pubkey")
        privkeyarray+=("$privatekey")
   done
   echo "genesis_public_key=${pubkeyarray[0]}" >>config.sh
   echo "genesis_private_key=${privkeyarray[0]}" >>config.sh

____HERE
)

SCRIPT="$(cat ~/shell/config.sh) ; $script;"
for i in ${!genesishost[*]} ; do
        SCR=${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/${password}}
        sshpass -p ${password} ssh -l ${username} ${genesishost[i]} "${SCR}"
done
```

`genesishost`, `password` and `username` are in `config.sh` file. Doing some **EOSIO** operations.

> What I need:

From the remote host, I want to append the config file with `"genesis_public_key"` and `"genesis_private_key"` which is on my local machine from which I am doing `ssh`.

This code generates a new config file on remote and appends these lines there. Do I need to ssh my local machine? If yes, the local machine cannot be the same always to add its ssh credentials. How can I accomplish this task? Please guide.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Instead put `genesis_public_key="ABC"` and `genesis_private_key="XYZ"` into the commands you execute locally, or perhaps add the `echo`s to `config.sh` locally before you `source` it.

Comment: I am doing some operation on remote, taking the values as `ABC` and `XYZ` from remote.

Comment: You seem to have a long string of questions which all circle around what seems to be essentially an [XY problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)  If the commands you want to execute are the same on all hosts, the simplest solution by far is to just pass in a static sequence of commands to `ssh`.

Comment: Then show us something more realistic instead of ABC and XYZ. There is still no sensible reason to append the values to a file instead of just execute them.

Comment: Edited the code. Please check.

Comment: You can remove `>>config.sh` in the remote script and instead have `ssh` append the result to the local file; `ssh remote "$script" >>config.sh`; but obviously if multiple hosts add the same variable name in the assignment, the last one wins.

Comment: So, doing ssh to my local machine again. Any alternative?

Comment: That's not what it's doing. It uses the output from `ssh` in the script you already have.

Comment: Got it! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script obviously only has access to files on the remote server, but instead of having it write to a (nonxistent) file, simply have it write out the output you want to add to the local file, and have the caller do the append.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source ~/shell/config.sh
script=$(cat <<\____HERE

   pubkeyarray=()
   privkeyarray=()
   for (( w=1; w<=3; w++))
   do
        # ... whatever ...
   done
   echo "genesis_public_key=${pubkeyarray[0]}"    # no redirect
   echo "genesis_private_key=${privkeyarray[0]}"  # no redirect

____HERE
)

SCRIPT="$(cat ~/shell/config.sh) ; $script;"
for i in ${!genesishost[*]} ; do
        SCR=${SCRIPT/PASSWORD/${password}}
        sshpass -p ${password} ssh -l ${username} ${genesishost[i]} "${SCR}"
done >>config.sh
```

Obviously, if multiple remote hosts print out assignments for variables with the same name, the last assignment in `config.sh` will replace all the earlier ones.

Comment: Yes, thank you! If in `$script` I want to echo some messages only on the console but not want them in the `config.sh`. Can we avoid some `echo` to be appended in the config?  Because this way everything getting appended in config whatever I am printing in `$script`.

Comment: Use standard error for diagnostic messages, always; `echo "$0: the end is nigh" >&2`

Comment: can you please suggest, If I want to modify `config.sh` from this code just like replacing the variable values. How can I use `sed` here?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to use `sed` for anything. Do you mean the file already contains an assignment and you want to replace it? Search for duplicates before asking, then ask a new question if you still can't figure it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568515/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-a-config-files-variable